# Get font properties of pdf text with pdfbox

Tags: java, fonts, properties, pdfbox

I am working on PDFBox to extract contents of a pdf file. I am able to extract text but i also need to get the font properties of the text. So can anyone help me in extracting font properties?

and I am also having problem in extracting certain characters properly. PDFBox gives '?' when it is unable to recognize the character. so also give me some suggestions to solve the problem if possible..

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

```
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument;  
import org.apache.pdfbox.util.PDFTextStripper;  
public class pdf2box {  
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        try
        {
    PDDocument pddDocument=PDDocument.load("table2.pdf");
    PDFTextStripper textStripper=new PDFTextStripper();
    System.out.println(textStripper.getText(pddDocument));
    textStripper.getFonts();



    pddDocument.close();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


}
```